# AWS Secrets Manager Resource policy unsupported principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I created a secret in AWS Secrets Manager. I want one IAM user and a federated user to be able to list, describe and retrieve the secret. I defined the following policy:

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/IAMUser1",
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/UAT-Developer/dev_user1@mycompany.com"
        ]  
    },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret", "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds", "secretsmanager:ListSecrets" ],
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

but it is throwing `This resource policy contains an unsupported principal`.

I also tried the below syntax for `Principal` but did not work.

```
"Principal" : {
          "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/IAMUser1",
          "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/UAT-Developer/dev_user1@mycompany.com" 
        }
```

Please help me get this correct.

Comment: Do you actually have a role in IAM called `UAT-Developer/dev_user1@mycompany.com`?
I'm guessing you don't as role names can't contain `/` characters and that the role is actually `UAT-Developer`. If that is the case just remove the `/dev_user1@mycompany.com` from your policy statement.

Comment: Yes, the role is there. It's federated with an AD group. So users part of the AD group will inherit the permissions attached to this role. From the notation UAT-Developer/dev_user1@mycompany.com, I mean dev_user1 from the UAT-Developer role.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. We have to put assumed-role instead of just role.

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789:assumed-role/UAT-Developer/dev_user1@mycompany.com
```